# How to show Image from local drive in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, image, fileserver

I am using ng-upload functionality of Angular JS and WEB API to upload the picture in my local drive whose path as follows:- "D:\Images\abc.jpg".

I am storing the file url of image in the database like in this case "D:\Images\abc.jpg" will be stored in Database.

I am trying to use following functionality to show the image in Angular JS:-

```
<img ng-src="file:///D:/Images/abc.jpg">
```

When I try to load the page in Google Chrome browser then I get the following error:-

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Images/abc.jpg

Currently the site is under development and I am using IISExpress to serve the HTML Page.

Users will upload many images using my site. 
What is the best way to  store and load images in Angular JS?

How to achieve this in detail?

Comment: Can you check it in other browsers and tell what's happening ?

Comment: Tried in Firefox. Not giving any error in Console but it is not populating the image as well.

Comment: Why you don't make a image folder inside your project ? it will be easy and accessible also..any reason not to make image folder inside your project ?